How to install files to output executable directory in CMake
I want to install some dlls to the executable output directory, I'm wondering why this doesn't work:
#Place the dlls in the exe directory
install(FILES ${MAIN_SRC_DIR}/ExternalDeps/OpenSSL/bin/libcrypto-3-x64.dll DESTINATION ${RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

I understand that the RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY is where the executable or library is put after building the target. However I get this message when configuring in CMake:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:68 (install):
  install FILES given no DESTINATION!

Why does it say I gave no destination?

Try printing the contents of RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY. Is it empty? The docs sound like the variable might only be initialized when a runtime target is created, so maybe you're trying to use the variable before creating any runtime target?

RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY is a property, not a variable. For load value of a property into the variable use get_property or similar command.

Note also, that installing something into the build directory contradicts the purpose of installing. If you just want to copy a file during the build of a project, then use file(COPY) or add_custom_command. Installing means to copy artifacts to some directory (install directory) after which build directory could be safely removed.

@Tsyvarev "Installing means to copy artifacts to some directory (install directory)".... The build directory is where you've put the build folder (the output of CMake), what's the "install directory"? I don't get why this isn't installing.

About installing you could read e.g. this
